# MySQL - can't fix error code 1142 - AFTER INSERT ON trigger with that updates row

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

The trigger I'm trying to create would do this: After insert on receipt('racun') table, I want it to change the final_price(koncni_znesek) because of the discount.amount_percent('popust.kolicina_procenti'). But I keep getting the error code 1142, which I unfortunately can't seem to fix even with a lot of documentation online.

Here's the code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER cena_po_popustu AFTER INSERT ON RACUN
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
    UPDATE
        racun r
        INNER JOIN 
        postavka p ON p.RACUN_ID = r.ID
        INNER JOIN 
        sobe s ON s.ID = p.SOBE_ID
        INNER JOIN 
        ponudba_prenocisce pp ON pp.ID = s.PONUDBA_PRENOCISCE_ID
        INNER JOIN 
        popusti pop ON pop.ID = pp.POPUSTI_ID
    SET
        NEW.koncni_znesek = r.koncni_znesek - ((pop.kolicina_procenti / 100) * r.koncni_znesek);
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My receipt('racun') table:

```
CREATE TABLE RACUN (
    ID INT not null,
    datum_cas DATETIME not null, 
    koncni_znesek INT not null,
    GOSTI_ID INT not null
);
ALTER TABLE RACUN ADD CONSTRAINT PK_RACUN PRIMARY KEY(ID);
ALTER TABLE RACUN ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RACUN_GOSTI FOREIGN KEY(GOSTI_ID) REFERENCES GOSTI(ID);
```

Comment: Try `SET  r.koncni_znesek = r.koncni_znesek - ((...))` instead of `SET  NEW.koncni_znesek = r.koncni_znesek - ((...))`

Comment: I had that before I tried the thing with NEW, also didn't work.

Comment: `A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.`. See [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).